# ¿Cómo insertar enbed content en un template de django?

Tags: django

En el panel de administración tengo un tipo de dato llamado Prueba, prueba tiene un field de tipo texto en el cual pego el código de contenido embebido (Como Twitter, youtube o facebook). A la hora de insertar este contenido en el template imprime, literalmente, el còdigo en el template.

```
class Prueba(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   url  = models.TextField()
   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Así está el template

```
{% if pruebas %}
  {% for prueba in pruebas %}
    {{ prueba.url }}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <p>No hay pruebas dispoibles.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Esto me funcionaría bien si buscara imprimir el atributo "name" de la clase, pero el atributo "url" debería de insertar esos datos en el template html, no mostar el código para insertarlo.

Así es como se ve el archivo html en el explorador.

[image: Vista html del template]

Comment: Usa el filtro `safe`. Quedaría así `{{ prueba.url|safe }}`. Mas información [aquí](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

Comment: ¡Excelente! Esto lo imprime. Solo tengo la duda. Lo imprime sin estilo. El contenido, por ejemplo Twitter, cuando lo inserta en el html se muestra ya con un estilo predefinido por Twitter. Mostrando la imagen de avatar y contenido multimedia del tweet. Pero aquí sólo imprime el texto y el enlace a la publicación original. Esto no sólo pasa cuando obtengo el código embeded desde un ciclo de python, sino si pego el código en el mismo template.html

Comment: Encontré mi error: Tenía activada una opción de proteccion de rastreo en Firefox que impedía que cargara el javascript de Twitter.